# merge folder in current directory using applescript

Tags: macos, copy, applescript, directory

Im wondering how to copy a folder that resides in the applescripts running directory to a specific folder on the MAC, making sure to merge the files/folders inside?

Cheers

K

Comment: 1) the directory the script is running in 2)a folder like /Desktop/Myfolder 3) Overwrite them (not delete them)

Comment: check out: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/320605/merge-folders-and-subfolders-in-macos/341906#341906

Answer (score 0):

```
set The_Moving_Folder to "Macintosh HD:Users:ComputerName:Desktop:Test1"
set The_Overwrite_Move_Location to "Macintosh HD:Users:ComputerName:Desktop:Test2"

do shell script "mv " & quoted form of (posix path of The_Moving_Folder) & " " & quoted form of (posix path of The_Overwrite_Move_Location)
```

The `mv` command will move directory paths from point A to point B. Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for because you have no code up. However based on the question and comment, this should do the trick. If you're looking at moving a file to a folder than you want the `cp` command.

For more data about these commands, run `man command_name` in terminal.